# Размещение Яндекс карты в непрямоугольном блок

Tags: svg, яндекс-карты, clip-path

Необходимо поместить Яндекс карту в непрямоугольный блок (например, в форме стрелки). Подскажите, пожалуйста, может, есть возможность через svg (у меня знания svg поверхностные) или как-то иначе. Знаю, что есть свойство css clip-path, но оно работает не во всех браузерах. Можно пробовать наложением фона, но это похоже на "костыль".

Comment: А какую форму вам надо? Если стрелку, то проще сделать прямоугольную карту и наложить поверх png элементы

Comment: Стрелку как домик. Просто там еще эту карту должен окружать фон не однородный, а с причудливым узором, поэтому получится, что эти png элементы будут частью фона, нужно четко состыковать, плюс следить, чтоб пропорции сохранялись при масштабировании.